# Problem with Pixelated fonts in @font-face on IE8

Tags: php, css, html, xhtml

This is happening just in IE 8

http://www.deviatebeta.co.uk/primary/

on the above URL if you hover over on "What we Do" on the menu, you should get a dropdown. I use @font-face to render special fonts. The dropdown is pixelated. Is there any way to fix this.

Can anyone please help me.

Thank you,
Karthik

Comment: Have you got the problem in IE7 or IE9 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use any IE filters for the drop down?

Comment: Set a background color or a background-image for the element while u set your filters. Then pixelation will reduce. Read this for more http://www.jonathancross.com/projects/Ugly_font_anti-aliasing_problem_in_Internet_Explorer_6_7_and_8.html.

Comment: I faced a similar problem myself :) - check this out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335829/ie-filter-antialiasing-problem

Comment: Awesome, Thx KAG I decided to remove the filter completely. It solved everything...