# text rendering is screwed with "gradient" on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, rgba

RGBA -- workaround for IE is “DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient".Found a **handy tool** provided by www.css3please.com for cross browser transparency,but applying this gradient on IE(IE8) -- works,but the text loses its clearness/legibility.

applying `georgia` to make the font look uniform on all the browsers,but the text does not appear properly after i apply gradient . Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/GJaDy

the code is--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.georgiaWithTransform{
    font-family: Georgia;
    height: 80px;
    width: 800px;
     font-family: "Georgia", Geneva  ;
    word-wrap:break-word;
      background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);  /* FF3+, Saf3+, Opera 10.10+, Chrome, IE9 */
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C969696,endColorstr=#4C969696); /* IE6–IE9 */
                zoom: 1;

 }
 .georgiaWithoutTransform{
    font-family: Georgia;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 800px;
     font-family: "Georgia", Geneva  ;
word-wrap:break-word;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);  /* FF3+, Saf3+, Opera 10.10+, Chrome, IE9 */

 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="georgiaWithTransform">Georgia does not appear properly with transformation in IE 8,and i do not understand why this is happening</div>
<div class="georgiaWithoutTransform">Georgia properly without transformation in IE 8,You can notice the difference in the appearance of the text here as compared to the top part( Noticeable only in IE)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cant understand why this is happening and badly need a workaround for this problem.

Here's a screen shot of the problem on IE8 --
[image]

Same happens on the fiddle as well.. problem is seen only on IE,not sure why..

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: just wanted to add,this problem is not seen on FF/Chrome/safari.. only on ie..

Comment: You might want to add a proper example of what is happening. ( http://jsfiddle.net )

Comment: @lollero have updated the code to give you and others a better view of my problem,please check the fiddle in IE to see my problem(text rendering on applying a gradient) -- check the fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/GJaDy/ .. any help is appreciated..

Comment: The gradient in your fiddle is non-existent. You've specified the same color as your start and end color. Also, hex values should only have 6 characters, not 8.

Comment: @Alexmorales was trying to attain cross browser transparency,i.e.Rgba workaround for IE.. as mentioned in the link i'd also included( www.css3please.com ).. that's y there's no gradient.. and making the color a proper hex does not change anything -- the text still remains disturbed..

Comment: That's strange because despite everything I had seen, the text looks fine for me in that fiddle. Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: @alexmorales added a screenshot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once with opacity filters in IE, the alternative that was suggested to me was using 2x2 image and background-repeat. In your case, you could try the same with a 1px width and the content height as height for your image with the desired gradient applied. This may not help you much but, here is the link to aforementioned question.

P.S : using an image as a workaround did work like a charm for me.

[IE Filter Antialiasing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335829/ie-filter-antialiasing-problem)

Comment: Thank you,i'll keep that as a last resort.. seems like using an image is the only workaround for every stupid IE problem..

Comment: Yeah i went through the same. If you do find a workaround, update!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, that's what I thought was happening. The filter's turning off the anti-aliasing in the font. [You can see a solution offered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761778/forcing-anti-aliasing-using-css-is-this-a-myth) Biziclop created a small jQuery script you can use and [has a sample of it working here](http://nadycoon.hu/special/archive/internet-explorer-force-antialias.html). This will force the browser to fake the anti-aliasing.

Comment: checked the answer,using plain js.. is there a way i can wrap it with plain JS??

Comment: also,he mentions that its a v memory hungry method -- would you suggest using it??.. or,is there any other way to achieve the same??

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't bother with trying to support rgba on IE. I would just make sure that it degrades gracefully and move on. I've managed to get clients and co-workers to understand that pages do not have to look identical in every browser. The only other solution I've seen would be the one Brutallus mentioned. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: thanks,searched -- found no articles.. guess this issue has no workaround.. accepting Brutallus's answer..